# Create a subdomain folder in another subdomain folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cpanel

I create a subdomain (site1.mysite.com) pointing to Document Root: /public_html/site1

Created another subdomain *.mysite.com pointing to Document Root: /public_html/site1/distributors

I've created rewrite rules to send the subdomain name to the respective pages and it works.

I've also for this case, in the rewrite cond for the second subdomain site, ignored site1.mysite.com.

But the 2 pages kept showing internal server error 500.

It was working fine till i changed the subdomains.

If any advise, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html

> Name-based virtual hosts for the best-matching set of s are processed in the order they appear in the configuration. The first matching ServerName or ServerAlias is used, with no different precedence for wildcards (nor for ServerName vs. ServerAlias).

So I would try to keep it simple, order them correctly and remove any rewrite or ignore rules.